# Has there been a comparison bewteen SIMPLE/SIMPLER and JFNK for steady CFD?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-equations, reference-request

I'm looking for a comparison between the Jacobian-Free Newton-Krylov (JFNK) method performance compared to the conventional CFD nonlinear solution methodologies like SIMPLE.

Does anyone know if such a document exists? Also, if anyone has any intuition on this without any direct evidence, I would like to hear about it.

Comment: See, for instance,  D.A. Knoll, D.E. Keyes, Jacobian-free Newton–Krylov methods: a survey of approaches and applications//Journal of Computational Physics 193 (2004) 357–397

Answer (score 2):

Below is a similar case in which a coupled method is compared with a SIMPLE-like segregated one. The author showed an impressive acceleration of convergence.

Darwish I. et al., A Coupled Incompressible Flow Solver on Structured Grids. Numerical Heat Transfer, 52, 2007(4).

[Coupled N-S solver](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10407790701372785)